# Getting input from console and listening JMS topic at the same time

Tags: java, jms, console-application

I wrote a jms application that runs until you close it.

```
        while(true){
            String c=ReceiveFromTopic();
               if (c1==null){
                 String s=scanner.nextLine()
               }
            }
```

in some point in this while I want to get input from console.

the problem is until input is given via console (which can be never) I cannot check the JMS topic.

I want to be able to listen the topic and when something is posted, immediately close the i/o and carry on some other calculations.

How can I change my code ? is there different a way to listen jms topic ?

Comment: use the onMessage method that allows you to manage the actions when a message is posted in the queue.

Comment: i need to use a topic also I want the program keep working.